# Adding reference/ Point to an external file from a protected folder

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, winforms

I am working on an existing client application. When this application is deployed by the deployment team it has a generic exe.config file.

I have created an application which gives user choices and based on their choices it creates the correct exe.config file. Now I just need to replace the generic exe.config file with my specific exe.config file and then launch the application.

My application works fine if I have write access to the folder where I have all the dlls and exes of the client application. I was replacing the generic config file with the newly created config file and then launching the application and it all worked fine.

Now the deployments team is planning create the folder inside Program Files folder to which my program wont have write permission to.

In this case I am looking for ideas how to point the generic config file to the specific config file which my program has created.

Anu ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can code the generic config file to reference the specific config **file** with the file or **configSource** attributes?

For Example:

generic config file

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="..\..\specific.config"></appSettings>
<configuration>
```

specific config file

```
<appSettings>
...
</appSettings>
```

More info on **file** and **configSource** here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228154(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228154%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)